# Product 360 degree slider speed

Tags: javascript, css

I am pretty new at javaScript and I am having trouble with adjusting the speed of the scrolling over the product. I want to make it faster. I tried it with couple of methods but without any success. There is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = init;

var product;
function init(){

    product1 = $('.product1').ThreeSixty({
        totalFrames: 97, // Total no. of image you have for 360 slider
        endFrame: 97, // end frame for the auto spin animation
        currentFrame: 1, // This the start frame for auto spin
        imgList: '.threesixty_images', // selector for image list
        progress: '.spinner', // selector to show the loading progress
         imagePath:'assets/product1/', // path of the image assets
        filePrefix: 'a', // file prefix if any
        ext: '.jpg', // extention for the assets
        height: 265,
        width: 400,
        navigation: true,
        disableSpin: true, // Default false
        responsive: true,           
    });

}
</script>
```

Do I have to edit this in JavaScript or it can be done in CSS?

Link to the site:
http://pappu-lighting.com/Series/Kutiq/LAST.html

the slider is on the second section in right. Thank you!

Comment: Do you have a `$(window).scroll(function(event) {` code too?

Comment: this is the whole JavaScript code for this